# Can I do Model->where('id', ARRAY) multiple where conditions?

Tags: php, laravel

The title says it all.

I get that I can do this :

```
DB::table('items')->where('something', 'value')->get()
```

But what I want to check the where condition for multiple values like so:

```
DB::table('items')->where('something', 'array_of_value')->get()
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 164):

There's [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses):

```
$items = DB::table('items')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

Answer (score 66):

You could use one of the below solutions:

```
$items = Item::whereIn('id', [1,2,..])->get();
```

or:

```
$items = DB::table('items')->whereIn('id',[1,2,..])->get();
```

Answer (score 34):

If you need by several params:

```
$ids = [1,2,3,4];
$not_ids = [5,6,7,8];
DB::table('table')->whereIn('id', $ids)
                  ->whereNotIn('id', $not_ids)
                  ->where('status', 1)
                  ->get();
```

Comment: for me it is very precise, plus Laravel way. Maybe it is case of taste. How it should look like for you to be more precise? Thanks!

Comment: There are other ways for doing this, so I said that but you are also right there may be a case of taste.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `whereIn` which accepts an array as second paramter.

```
DB:table('table')
   ->whereIn('column', [value, value, value])
   ->get()
```

You can chain where multiple times.

```
DB:table('table')->where('column', 'operator', 'value')
    ->where('column', 'operator', 'value')
    ->where('column', 'operator', 'value')
    ->get();
```

This will use `AND` operator. if you need `OR` you can use `orWhere` method.

For advanced `where` statements

```
DB::table('table')
    ->where('column', 'operator', 'value')
    ->orWhere(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('column', 'operator', 'value')
            ->where('column', 'operator', 'value');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: your chaining method worked for me in the case of AND operator!
Thanks

Comment: Can I do `->where('id', 'IN', [1, 2, 3])`?

Answer (score 4):

If you are searching by ID you can also use:

```
$items = Item::find(array_of_ids);
```

Comment: Coolest solution! Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me
fetch just id then search in array

```
$shops = Shop::Where('user_id', Auth::id())->get('id');
$categories = Category::whereIn('shop_id',$shops)->paginate(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
DB:table('table')->where([
    'column' => 'value',
    'column' => 'value',
    'column' => 'value',
])->get()
```

Instead of that:

```
DB:table('table')->where('column', 'value')
    ->where('column', 'value')
    ->where('column', 'value')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

$whereData = [['name', 'test'], ['id', '<>', '5']];

$users = DB::table('users')->where($whereData)->get();

Answer (score -3):

**WHERE AND SELECT Condition In Array Format Laravel**

```
use DB;

$conditions = array(
    array('email', '=', 'user@gmail.com')
);
$selected = array('id','name','email','mobile','created');
$result = DB::table('users')->select($selected)->where($conditions)->get();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP was asking if there was a way to get the query builder to accept an array of VALUES as the where clause's value, not an array of conditions.