# Cast Laravel Collection into array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my code
`$titles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title');`
How Can I cast *$**titles*** from a Laravel 5 collection into an associative array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the ID in the function, and call from the Model:

```
$titles = Role::lists('title', 'id')->toArray();
```

Or call directly as you are doing:

```
$titles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title', 'id');
```

In this case, in an select field for example, the `id` will be the option value.

Comment: the result is still a laravel collection, I want to cast this collection into a PHP associative array.

Comment: Try to call `toArray()` in the collection result.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Laravel does not contain a `lists` method anywhere which returns a `Collection`, hence `toArray` should not be necessary and would result in a fatal error for anyone else.  Are you overriding some functions somewhere?

Comment: Actually, you are right @user3158900. I've changed my answer again.

Comment: How to convert back "toArray()" into normal eloquent model ? Is it possible ?

Comment: @Ephra I don't think there is a function that does exactly this, but you can try to use `whereIn` with the IDs. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706603/laravel-whereid-array-multiple-where-conditions-laravel-4

Answer (score 2):

A laravel collection has a `toArray` method that will return a numerically keyed array of the contents. (The indexes will be keyed exactly as they are in the collection. To reset them call `values` on the collection first.)

```php
$titles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title');

$result = $titles->toArray();
```

For an associative array you will need to do this manually using something like this.

```php
$titles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title', 'id');

$result = [];

foreach($titles as $title) {
    // using an ID as the key and title as the value
    $result[$title->id] = $title->title;
}
```

Comment: 1. The `lists('title')` call returns an array, you can't run `toArray()` on that. 2. When you do `lists('title', 'id')`, you get an associative array of id => title elements. No need to populate the results array manually. Just did a quick tinker check and it works great in L5.1 at least. That said, the behaviour was different in L4, but the question is tagged L5.